# Downloading and Opening a File

Tags: download, applescript

How can I use applescript to download a file from a specified link and open this downloaded file. Is there a way to do this without needing to specify the exact path to the downloaded file to open this file?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

You can download a file to the current directory with `curl -O` and open the newest file with `open "$(ls -t|head -n1)"`:

```
do shell script "cd ~/Desktop
curl -LO http://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico
open \"$(ls -t|head -n1)\""
```

`curl -L` follows location headers (redirections).

If `curl` downloads the file with no filename extension, try to use `wget --content-disposition` instead.